# how to show on TextView 3 axes of accelerometer

Tags: java, android

I want to print the three values of each axes(scaledX , scaledY, scaledZ) of `accelerometer` in three TextView.

Can somebody help me?
thanks.

CODE:

MainActivity.java.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback {

    private TextView  mAccelerometerx, mAccelerometery, mAccelerometerz;
        mAccelerometerx =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ejex);
        mAccelerometery =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ejey);
        mAccelerometerz =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ejez);

 private void updateAccelerometerValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic ){

        double accelerometerx = SensorTagData.extractAccelerometer(characteristic, mAccelerometerx);
        double accelerometery = SensorTagData.extractAccelerometer(characteristic, mAccelerometery);
        double accelerometerz = SensorTagData.extractAccelerometer(characteristic, mAccelerometerz);

        mAccelerometerx.setText(String.format("%.4f", accelerometerx));
        mAccelerometery.setText(String.format("%.4f", accelerometery));
        mAccelerometerz.setText(String.format("%.4f", accelerometerz));
    }

}
```

---

SensorData.java

```
public class SensorData {

  public static double [] extractAccelerometer(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {

        Integer x = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 0);
        Integer y = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 1);
        Integer z = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 2) * -1;

        double scaledX = x / 64.0;
        double scaledY = y / 64.0;
        double scaledZ = z / 64.0;

        return new double[] {scaledX, scaledY, scaledZ};
    }
 }
```

Comment: What's the problem? I see code, but no errors or unexpected outputs. Can you post those please. Where are you passing the Sensor Data double to write to the text view...?

Answer (score 0):

private void updateAccelerometerValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic ){

```
    double accelerometerx = SensorTagData.extractAccelerometer(characteristic, mAccelerometerx);
    double accelerometery = SensorTagData.extractAccelerometer(characteristic, mAccelerometery);
    double accelerometerz = SensorTagData.extractAccelerometer(characteristic, mAccelerometerz);

    mAccelerometerx.setText(String.format("%.4f", accelerometerx));  //ERROR HERE
    mAccelerometery.setText(String.format("%.4f", accelerometery));  //ERROR HERE
    mAccelerometerz.setText(String.format("%.4f", accelerometerz));  //ERROR HERE
}
```

ERROR Type
The method extractAccelerometer(BluetoothGattCharacteristic) in the type SensorTagData is not applicable for the arguments (BluetoothGattCharacteristic, TextView)

I know I am giving more than two parameters, but if I delete "accelerometerx", "accelerometery" , "accelerometerz" the error disappears but I suppose will not see anything.